# VBA, Numberformat date and custom

Tags: excel, vba

I have a issue with `numberformat` my date.

```
.Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = Worksheets("Control Manager").Range("G2").Value  'Col A and date
.Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = Worksheets("Control Manager").Range("G2").NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
```

But this value gives me "FALSE" .

I also would like to know how to number format custom, `#,##0_ ;[Red]-#,##0`

```
.Range("B" & lastrow + 1).Formula = "='Risk'!C" & lastrowfv - 1 & "+SUM(lastweek!D33:D36)"
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `X = Y = Z`, like on your second line, means `X = (Y = Z)` which assigns `True` or `False` to `X`depending on whether `Y` equals `Z`.

Comment: one option is to declare the format on a range after you insert a formula, e.g., range("a1").numberformat = "yyyy/mm/dd"

Comment: `.Range("A" & lastrow + 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` seemed to do the trick, thanks guys.